# Power query editor 24 hours (HH:MM:SS) error

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Came across this from an issue I appear to be having with the power query editor, tried different options but this appears to be closest to the issue I am having when editing time/ duration over 24 hours.

Please accept my apologies, fairly new to power query editor.

I have attached a screenshot of the error I am receiving any belongings is much appreciated.

More information can be provided if needed.

When I click show error the second ‘let’ highlights and token eof error appears, assuming this is something to do with parentheses or commas in the query.

[image: error message]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: Why do you have two `let`s in the same query?

Answer (score 0):

The Power Query can only have 1 top-level `let` expression. You'll want to structure your query like this. **Edit in the advanced editor**

```
let
    Source = ...,

    DurationFromYourText = (text as text) as duration =>
        let
            Duration = ...
        in 
            Duration,


    Invoked = DurationFromYourText()
in
    Invoked
```

## Trouble over 24 hours

That's because 128 hours is an invalid value `128:22:13`. If you're in-range then the built-in formatter works

```
Duration.FromText("5.08:22:13")
```

[Duration.FromText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-fromtext) says it uses the format

```
(-)hh:mm(:ss(.ff))
(-)ddd(.hh:mm(:ss(.ff)))


(All ranges are inclusive)
ddd: Number of days.
hh: Number of hours, between 0 and 23.
mm: Number of minutes, between 0 and 59.
ss: Number of seconds, between 0 and 59.
ff: Fraction of seconds, between 0 and 9999999.
```

Comment: Thank you ninMonkey for your help. Assuming in the query. I am into input the times in the fields following as duration?